# Basic nginx proxy_pass configuration doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I have this basic nginx configuration

```
http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root /data/upl;
    }
}
```

I also have `index.html` on `/data/upl` on nginx.

When i go to `http://localhost` - i get back the HTML in Chrome.

After i'm changing the location matcher from `/` to `/test/` and go to `http://localhost/test` I get back error 404 of nginx in chrome.

that's the updated configuration:

```
http {
    server {
        location /test/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root /data/upl;
    }
}
```

Please help with understanding this issue (why it  doesn't work).

Comment: Did you try adding `listen 8080;` to your proxy_pass server block?

Comment: Also, don't think you can use the same port for nginx and service behind the proxy pass.

Comment: @sunknudsen why to add listen 8080? I want to listen on the default port, 80.
and if I can't , why it's working with the `/` location?

Comment: Good point, didn't know nginx defaulted to 80 (I've always included a `listen 80` directive). But why is `/data/upl` listening on the same port as the service to which you wish to proxy? Wouldn't that cause a conflict?

Comment: I believe the problem may be as simple as removing the forward slash from the location `location /test`

Comment: @EternalHour . sorry but it still doesn't work :( .

Answer (score 0):

I think that configuration may be too basic. You're using a forward slash in the location, which means you also need to tell nginx what type of file(s) to look for by using the `index` directive.

**Excerpt from documentation**

> If a request ends with a slash, NGINX treats it as a request for a directory and tries to find an index file in the directory. The index directive defines the index file’s name (the default value is index.html). To continue with the example, if the request URI is /images/some/path/, NGINX delivers the file /www/data/images/some/path/index.html if it exists. If it does not, NGINX returns HTTP code 404 (Not Found) by default

I don't understand why you are using a proxy, doesn't seem needed. Here is the configuration I would suggest using.

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /data/upl;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location /test {
  }
}
```

There will need to be an index.htm or index.html file in /data/upl/test or a 404 will be generated.

Comment: thanks for the clarification about the forward slash. in this `/data/upl` directory I do have `index.html` so it doesn't explain why it's not working. i tried without the forward slash and it still doesn't work.

my main focus here is understanding why it doesn't work, not to workaround it with simpler configuration. i need to get a good understanding because i need to build something more complex.

Comment: It doesn't work because you need an index file in `/test` also